# How to paint specific rows in a listbox (WPF app)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am writing a project that includes a WPF window that contains a listbox. the listbox is uses binding to a list of tasks (a class I've created). I am trying to have some specific rows of the listbox painted and some specific rows to have colored borders based on the fields of the items in the list. how do i add a paint/brush method for specific rows to a listbox and not the whole listbox?
Below is the XAML properties of the listbox:

```
<ListBox Name="Tasks" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tasks,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="199" Margin="303,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="439" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <ListBox.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0.294"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ListBox.RenderTransform>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question [Listbox item WPF, different background color for different items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099694/listbox-item-wpf-different-background-color-for-different-items)

Comment: ListBox.ItemContainerStyle - provide custom style for ListBoxItems in that property. You can set BorderBrush and Background of ListBoxItems

Answer (score 0):

The ItemsControl has a special feature for selecting templates for items shown in the control. In the following sample I illustrate the use of the DataTemplateSelector

First the XAML. In the Resource  section different data templates are defined for the different types of items you want to show in the ListBox, and there is a reference to the DataTemplateSelector (defined in the C# code later):

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="DataWindow"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
   <Window.Resources>
      <!-- The data template selector -->
      <local:DataItemTemplateSelector x:Key="DataItemTemplateSelector"/>
      <!-- Data template for a normal data item -->
      <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalDatatemplate">
         <Border Width="200"
                 Margin="0"
                 Background="White"
                 BorderThickness="2"
                 Padding="3"
                 BorderBrush="Transparent">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       FontSize="20"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       Background="Transparent"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Header}"/>
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
      <!-- Data template for a special data item -->
      <DataTemplate x:Key="SpecialDatatemplate">
         <Border Width="200"
                 Margin="0"
                 Background="Yellow"
                 BorderThickness="2"
                 Padding="3"
                 BorderBrush="Blue">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       FontSize="20"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       Background="Transparent"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Header}"/>
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <ListBox x:Name="DataListBox"   
               Margin="50"
               Width="Auto"
               Height="Auto"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DataWindow, Path=DataList}"
               ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DataItemTemplateSelector}"/>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

And then the C# code, there the DataItemTemplateSelector is defined and the DataList with some testdata:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestWpfApp
{
   // Different types of items on the list
   public enum DataItemType
   {
      Normal,
      Special
   }
   // Items on the list
   public class DataItem
   {
      public string Header { set; get; }
      public DataItemType DataType { set; get; }
   }
   // Data template selector for items on the list
   public class DataItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
   {
      public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object dataItem, DependencyObject container)
      {
         // Check that everyting is OK
         if ((dataItem != null) && (dataItem is DataItem))
         {
            // Switch on the data type
            switch (((DataItem)(dataItem)).DataType)
            {
               case DataItemType.Normal:
                  // Return the data template for a normal data item 
                  return Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("NormalDatatemplate") as DataTemplate;
               case DataItemType.Special:
                  // Return the data template for a special data item 
                  return Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("SpecialDatatemplate") as DataTemplate;
               default:
                  return null;
            }
         }
         return null;
      }
   }
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      // The list of data to show in the list box
      public List<DataItem> DataList { set; get; }
      // The constructor of the main window
      public MainWindow()
      {
         // Some test data
         this.DataList = new List<DataItem>();
         this.DataList.Add(new DataItem() { Header = "Item 1", DataType = DataItemType.Normal });
         this.DataList.Add(new DataItem() { Header = "Item 2", DataType = DataItemType.Normal });
         this.DataList.Add(new DataItem() { Header = "Item 3", DataType = DataItemType.Special });
         this.DataList.Add(new DataItem() { Header = "Item 4", DataType = DataItemType.Normal });
         // Initializing the window
         InitializeComponent();
      }
   }
}
```

I hope you get the idea of using the DataTemplateSelector, and then you can style your ListBox and the different types of items in it